# Postgresql max time value

Tags: sql, postgresql, time, types

In the postgresql documentation related to date/time types. It is stated that the type time  can have a max value of 24:00:00. Can someone could explain to me the purpose of settings this value to this instead of 23:59:59 ? There's maybe a reason for this but i just don't get it.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there is a leap second the traditional way of representing that is `23:59:60` but it looks like PostgreSQL chose to handle it with the hour `24`.

Comment: Also see "A [discussion of ISO 8601](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-time.html) has been written by Markus Kuhn." which includes: *As every day both starts and ends with midnight, the two notations 00:00 and 24:00 are available to distinguish the two midnights that can be associated with one date. This means that the following two notations refer to exactly the same point in time: 

    **1995-02-04 24:00 = 1995-02-05 00:00**

In case an unambiguous representation of time is required, 00:00 is usually the preferred notation for midnight and not 24:00.*